# Lock screen after > 99 minutes in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu, ubuntu-15.04

I'm using Kubuntu 15.04 and the [Plasma 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_5) system settings GUI has a very annoying (presumably artificial) upper limit of locking the screen after 99 minutes. Is there some alternative way to set this to any value I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around my config files a bit and found a `~/.config/kscreenlockerrc` file with contents

```
[Daemon]
Timeout=99
```

and was able to confirm this was the correct file by changing the 'Lock screen after' setting in the System Settings application (Desktop Behavior -> Screen Locking) and observing the Timeout value change. [You can change this value to values greater than 99](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344967#c7).

I also filed a bug against systemsettings: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=350601